# Using bitwise & on boolean

Tags: c++, boolean, bitwise-and

Consider the following code snippet:

```
main()
{
    bool flag = true;             //line 1
    flag &= funcReturningBool();  //line 2
    flag &= funcReturningBool2();
    flag &= funcReturningBool3();
    //....
    //....
    //....
    //so many such cases
}

bool funcReturningBool()
{
    bool ret = false;
    // my logic which may (not) modify ret
    return ret;
}

bool funcReturningBool2()
{
    bool ret = false;
    // my logic which may (not) modify ret
    return ret;
}

bool funcReturningBool3()
{
    bool ret = false;
    // my logic which may (not) modify ret
    return ret;
}
```

The **static code analyzer** tool points out the following issue (on line 2):

"*Bitwise operator is being applied to a signed type. The resulting value may not be as expected.*"

Can someone point out if I'm doing something wrong?
Also prescribe some useful/logical alternative methods to achieve the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just shouldn't use a bitwise operator on Boolean values. Apparently the compiler promotes the output of `funcReturningBool` or the variable `flag` to a signed integer, and warns you of possible unexpected effects.

You should stick to Boolean operators. Had `&&=` existed, you could have written `flag &&= funcReturningBool();`. Instead, use `flag = flag && funcReturningBool();`